# Using a jitted function with a for loop inside

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, jit, numba

I have the following piece of code

```
@njit
    def ss(w,g,sm):
        kb = ( (α/(r*(1+τk)))**((1-γ)/(1-γ - α)) )* \
        ( (γ/(w*(1+τn)))**(γ/(1-γ-α)) )* \
        (smat*(1-τo))**(1/(1-γ-α)) ## ss capital

        nb = (1+τk)*r*γ/((1+τn)*w*α)*kb ## ss labor

        πb = (1-τo)*sm*(kb**α)*(nb**γ)- (1+τn)*w*nb-(1+τk)*r*kb-cf #ss profit
        W = πb/(1-0.0196) ## error in the code
        for i in range(ns):
            for j in range(nτ):
                xb[i,j] = 1 if W[i,j]>=0 else xb[i,j]
        we = sum(W*g*xb) - ce
        return we
```

As far as I know it should work, but I keep getting the following errors

```
TypingError: Invalid use of Function(<built-in function setitem>) with argument(s) of type(s): (readonly array(float64, 2d, C), tuple(int64 x 2), float64)
 * parameterized
In definition 0:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 1:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 2:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 3:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 4:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 5:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 6:
```

I am still figuring out my way around python. I know it comes becomes of the fact that I am using njit, but what part exactly is causing it? If I remove the for loop it works fine, but I wonder what in the for loop could be causing this?

Reproducible example

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
class rep:
    def __init__(self, A = 1, B=2, C = 3, D = 4):
        self.A, self.B,self.C, self.D = A,B,C,D


def op(cls):
    A,B,C,D = cls.A, cls.B,cls.C, cls.D
    xb = np.zeros([10,10])
    @njit
    def rep1(w,g,sm):
        kb = A*3 + B*2
        nb = C*3 - D*w
        pib = sm*kb - nb
        W = pib/4
        for i in range(10):
            for j in range(10):
                xb[i,j] = 1 if W[i,j]>=0 else xb[i,j]
        we = np.sum(w*xb*g)
        return we
    return rep1


g = np.zeros([10,10])
sm = np.ones([10,10])
w = 1
r = rep()
rep1 = op(r)
print(rep1(w,g,sm))
```

Comment: It is almost impossible to answer a question with a lot of variables, without what they are. (Arrays-> which shape, Tuples,... Please add a full working pure Python/Numpy example. Also make sure that you know how global variables are handeld in Numba (they are compile time constant, if you want to change them you have to recompile, which is likely not wanted)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Added reproducible example. All arrays are numpy arrays. The error seems to be from the for loop, because xb is defined outside the function. But even if I define it inside it still gives me the same error. It will only work if xb is an argument, but I was under the impression that njit works on numpy arrays even if they are not arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be related to thing @max9111 mentioned in comments - `xb` array is created outside jitted function and therefore it cannot be modified inside. I changed your code a little by moving `xb` outside of `op` and passing it to `rep1` as a parameter and it can be successfully executed:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
class rep:
    def __init__(self, A = 1, B=2, C = 3, D = 4):
        self.A, self.B,self.C, self.D = A,B,C,D


def op(cls):
    A,B,C,D = cls.A, cls.B,cls.C, cls.D
    @njit
    def rep1(w,g,sm,xb):
        kb = A*3 + B*2
        nb = C*3 - D*w
        pib = sm*kb - nb
        W = pib/4
        for i in range(10):
            for j in range(10):
                xb[i,j] = 1 if W[i,j]>=0 else xb[i,j]
        we = np.sum(w*xb*g)
        return we
    return rep1


g = np.zeros([10,10])
sm = np.ones([10,10])
xb = np.zeros([10,10])
w = 1
r = rep()
rep1 = op(r)
print(rep1(w,g,sm,xb))
```

Comment: This works but I was hoping to not have to define xb as a variable. Thank you very much though.